# Como pegar os elements de um json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tenho o retorno de uma requisicao no seguinte formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ali em options existem os tipos de cartoes o json retornou. Quero pegar cada um dos tipos sem precisar digitar manualmente o nome deles.

Atualmente consigo pegar fazendo isso:

`response.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options.AMEX`

Mas assim preciso digitar o nome de cada um. Eu quero contar quantas opções tem e pega-las dinamicamente.
Alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que você mostrou, `response.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options` traz o objeto todo.

> Eu quero contar quantas opções tem e pega-las dinamicamente.

Não sei se entendi bem, mas dá para pegar as bandeiras extraindo as chaves do objeto:

```
var options = response.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options;
var bandeiras = Object.keys(options);
console.log(bandeiras.length + ' bandeiras disponíveis');

// Loop pelas chaves pegando os dados de cada bandeira
for(var i=0; i<bandeiras.length; i++) {
    console.log(options[bandeiras[i]]);
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, deu certo aqui.

Comment: @Thiago Se a resposta resolveu o problema, não deixe de marcar ✓.